# Spring Security OAuth2 supporting Facebook appsecret_proof

Tags: spring-boot, facebook, spring-oauth2

I am able to login with Facebook into my SpringBoot application only if I disable the `"Require App Secret"` option in the Facebook Developer application configuration.
When the extra (recommended) security check is enabled I get an error

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [invalid_user_info_response]
 An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the UserInfo Resource: Error details: [UserInfo Uri: 
   https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email, Error Code: {message=API calls from the server 
    require an appsecret_proof argument, type=GraphMethodException, code=100, fbtrace_id=xxxx}]
```

It is evident that Spring Security tries to access Facebook (calling `https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email`) to retrieve the authenticated user but it fails to pass the extra parameter `appsecret_proof`.

It is not immediately clear (after digging into SpringSecurity documentation and forums) how I can let Spring add the extra token.

Comment: Searching for “proof” across the repo https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth doesn’t give a single hit, so they might not have implemented this yet?

Comment: What behavior do you get when you use [Spring Security's Facebook sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/master/servlet/spring-boot/java/oauth2/login)?

Comment: @CBroe, the project you linked to is deprecated and support has moved over to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security.

Comment: Indeed I don't use Spring Social or Spring Security Oauth, both deprecated. I have integrated Facebook login using Spring Security, and it works fine unless I disable the "Require App Secret" option

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar situation - I could not log in to my application using the facebook user account.

First make sure that the given client id and secret id are correct (sometimes it can be confused with your other project). If you are sure that the entered data is okay, I would start by checking the available permits. So open the **facebook login** plugin panel (you should have a tab on the right side of the screen).

[image: Facebook plugin]

For my case, the following configuration was sufficient:

[image]

What's more, check the available permission and features:

[image]

**public_profile** access is required to extract basic information of a user who wants to log in to your website. In addition, it is also worth adding an email request.
[image]

Also check the configuration for the facebook client, which allows you to get the user token:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          facebook:
            clientId: your-client-id
            clientSecret: your-client-secret
            redirectUri: "{baseUrl}/api/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}" # Note that facebook now mandates the use of https redirect URIs, so make sure your app supports https in production
            scope:
              - email
              - public_profile
        provider:
          facebook:
            authorizationUri: https://www.facebook.com/v3.0/dialog/oauth
            tokenUri: https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/oauth/access_token
            userInfoUri: https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/me?fields=id,first_name,middle_name,last_name,name,email
```

In my case, the above configuration was enough for the user to authorize himself on an external website.